# Comparing SQl Date With C# Input values

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Hi i have to compare the date time sent from C# code to the SQLServer along with milliseconds.

### I have converted the date as follows..

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();
        MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                         provider);
```

### I have set the above date to an SP.

But when i send it to the data base only the following value is send "2013-05-06 14:33:13 PM" From the C# code.
When I Try To convert the value in Data base the value of millisecond is missing there. I convert the above using convert as follows in the SQl server

```
Select convert(varchar(23),@ModifiedDt,109)
```

It gives the value as follows "May  6 2013  2:33:13:00" For the input Given From C# code. But When the Data in data base is converted, it is as Follows " May  6 2013  2:33:13:96". So The Value Of date miss match in mill seconds.I have to check even the milliseconds to find weather the transaction is genuine. Some one plz tell How to send the value From C# Code to overcome the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, instead of passing the value as datetime, I recommend to pass it as an ISO 8601 (ex:-'2011-08-02T05:07:27.000') string. you can direcly use the string in sql comparision. It solves your problem.

Comment: But The Data in the database is in Datetime Format.Whether both can be compare able....

Comment: Yes, you can compare simply compare using that string. for example:

SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Time < '2011-08-02T05:07:27.000')


you can replace the above mentioned date and time with your variable.